# Asp.net Core post form data when use multiple model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

**Edit**
When i want to submit `form` models value show null in `Action` in Asp.net core 2.2. I have a `ComplexViewModel` contains 2 `Model` like this :

**Complex ViewModel**

```
public class CreateQuestionComplexModel
{
    public questionViewModel questionViewModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Group> GroupModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateQuestion(CreateQuestionComplexModel model)
    {
       return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateQuestion(CreateQuestionComplexModel model)
    {
     //model is null here
     //ModelState

    }
```

**here is my view**

```
@model porseman.Models.ComplexModel.CreateQuestionComplexModel

@Html.PartialAsync("SideBarMenu", Model.GroupModel)

     <form class="row" asp-Controller="Question" asp-Action="CreateQuestion" method= "post">
          <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-10">
                 <input asp-for="questionViewModel.Title" type="text" class="form-control" />
             </div>
             <label asp-for="questionViewModel.Title" class="control-label col-xs-2"></label>
          </div>

          <input type="button" value="submit" class="btn" />
     </form>
```

Now when i submit form all value are `null` in `Action`. I found out after reviewing the codes that all inputs **id** get prefix `questionViewModel_Title` and all input **name** `questionViewModel.Title`. 
Now how can i post data to `Action` **Or** how can i remove prefix?

Comment: Tuples aren't supported in model-binding. Use another class (a view model) to encapsulate the stuff in the tuple, and then use that as your model.

Comment: @ChrisPratt First i use `complex ViewModel`. But there was the same problem. for example when i use `@model.ComplexViewModel.Title` input **id**  turned out to `ComplexViewModel_Title`

Comment: That's not a problem, that's by design. Periods are invalid characters for an id attribute based on the HTML spec. As a result, they're changed to underscores for that attribute. However, the idea has nothing to do with the data that is posted or model-binding, so it doesn't matter. The name attribute is what matters.

Comment: @ChrisPratt All input **name** display `ComplexViewModel.name` and all input **id** display `ComplexViewModel_id` and the problem is `null` value in `controller`. How can i to solve it?

Comment: Don't add the "@Model." bit to `asp-for`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I change it to `asp-for="ComplexViewModel.Title"` but shows `ComplexViewModel.name` for **name** and `ComplexViewModel_id` for **id** again.

Comment: *Just* `Title`. No prefix needed.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I edited question. please look at it again. If i just write `Title` get error.

Comment: How did you post the data , the code `<input type="button" value="submit" class="btn" />` won't submit the form data , do you have a javascript function which trigger by button click ? try using `<input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" />` to submit , and remove js function if exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve problem with add `id` manualy.

**Try this**

```
@model porseman.Models.ComplexModel.CreateQuestionComplexModel

@Html.PartialAsync("SideBarMenu", Model.GroupModel)

 <form class="row" asp-Controller="Question" asp-Action="CreateQuestion" method= "post">
      <div class="form-group">

         <div class="col-xs-10">
             <input asp-for="questionViewModel.Title" id="Title" type="text" class="form-control" />
         </div>

      </div>

      <input type="button" value="submit" class="btn" />
 </form>
```

Now `id` is `Title` not `questionViewModel_Title` and in controller you can get form data value.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC Core 3, Html elements with "asp-for" values not in the model will show as build errors.

There is however a way of posting back values to another action using the HTML "name" attribute. Simply set the "name" value to the action attribute to bind to. In your case, values are the same as suggested in the asp-for attribute

Here is an example where an action does not take the original model, but a list and an integer to resize some image files

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult EditImages(List<string> filenames, int percentage)
```

The Razor view contains one input that has the integer value (in this case a RANGE element) and an array of strings where multiple hidden elements are given the same value for the name attribute

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="99" value="50" class="w-100" id="inputSizePercent" name="percentage">

@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Images.Count; index++)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="filenames" value="@Model.Images[index].Filename" />
}
```